# ArgumentNullExcpetionWasUnhandled VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, specially since I've already used the command ftp.upload(localpath,ftppath)

```
Imports System.IO.DriveInfo
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports EnterpriseDT.Net.Ftp
Public Class Form1
    Dim allDrives() As DriveInfo = DriveInfo.GetDrives()
    Dim ftp As New FTPConnection
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        UploadDiskReport()
    End Sub
    Public Sub UploadDiskReport()
        Dim d As DriveInfo
        Dim UnitFile As New StreamWriter("C:\Users\klein\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Filename.sys")
        For Each d In allDrives
            UnitFile.WriteLine("Drive: " & d.Name)
            If d.IsReady = True Then
                UnitFile.WriteLine("  Volume label: " & d.VolumeLabel)
                UnitFile.WriteLine("  Available space to current user: " & Format((((d.AvailableFreeSpace / 1024) / 1024) / 1024), "0.00") & "GB")
                UnitFile.WriteLine("  Total available space: " & Format((((d.TotalFreeSpace / 1024) / 1024) / 1024), "0.00") & "GB")
                UnitFile.WriteLine("  Total size of drive: " & Format((((d.TotalSize / 1024) / 1024) / 1024), "0.00") & "GB")
            End If
        Next
        UnitFile.Close()
        ftp.UploadFile("C:\Users\klein\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Filename.sys", "Filename.sys")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Where does the exception happen? What's the message? What's the stack trace?

Comment: Why are you writing to `Microsoft\Windows`?

Comment: @SLaks: I may be wrong with that, but I think a user is always able to write under `C:\Users\[user_name]` without permission elevation, so it should not matter which folder under that is being used.

Comment: I get the error on ftp.UploadFile(), this is the message: http://i.imgur.com/DMkmM.jpg

Comment: @Neolisk: Correct.  However, he should not be writing to that folder.

Comment: @blacblu: What's the stack trace?

Comment: @SLaks: you probably also don't like how it submits on Enter? :)

Comment: Yes, I don't know what is the stack trace. EDIT: Found it: http://pastebin.com/RxiPJNy7

Comment: I just realized what the problem was. I was inserting this code block before making the connection to the server on my software.